Procedural generation fails when I introduce 'on button hold' event; Unity Engine; C#
I've set a very simple procedural generation in C# for a Unity project consisting of two scripts:
One (PlatformMove.cs) which moves the section each frame and deletes it when it hits a Trigger:
public class PlatformMove : MonoBehaviour

private void Update()
{
    transform.position += new Vector3(0,0,-3) *Time.deltaTime;
    Debug.Log("bp is true");
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("DestroySection"))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("DESTROYED");
    }
}

And a second script (SectionTrigger.cs) which manages the creation of a new section when another trigger is hit by the player object:
public GameObject roadSection;

private float zpos = 26f; 

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("TriggerSection"))
    {
        Instantiate(roadSection, new Vector3(0, 0, zpos), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

In short, this mimics an endless runner type of project similar to Subway Surfer where the planes move and the player is static.
This runs fine on itself, however I wanted it to work on button hold by adding a UI button and editing PlatformMove.cs like this:
public class PlatformMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool bp = false;

    public void Move()
    {
        bp=true;
        transform.position += new Vector3(0,0,-3) *Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("bp is true");
    }

    public void NotMove()
    {
        bp=false;
        Debug.Log("bp is false");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {   
        if (bp ==true)
        Move();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("DestroySection"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Debug.Log("DESTROYED");
        }
    }

I added a bool which indicates if the button is pressed or not;
However when I do the above and run it, the second section is spawned on the trigger as expected:
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("TriggerSection"))
{
    Instantiate(roadSection, new Vector3(0, 0, zpos), Quaternion.identity);
}

but it doesn't move and once the first section is deleted, the Update method no longer seems to occur - indicated by the lack of debug messages once:
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("DestroySection"))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        Debug.Log("DESTROYED");
    }
}

occurs.
To clarify, the PlatformMove.cs is assigned to a prefab, so the script is present in every clone(spawn) of the original prefab - in theory it should work fine as the rules will still apply but I guess I'm missing something.
I can't determine why once the first section is destroyed, the update methods stops working
My knowledge is fairly limited but by adding a debug message to the Update method I managed to at least find out that it stops once the section is deleted.
If I move the new section manually during runtime, all triggers work fine, new section is spawned, old one is deleted.
No errors or warnings are visible in the console either.

bp starts out as false... and then Move is never called, and so bp is never set to true. Is that right? It's unclear what the intent here is meant to be. By the way, you can write if (bp) instead of if (bp == true)

Yes, bp starts as false since I don't want the plane to move before I've pressed the button. Once I press it, bp = true and Move() is called. Thanks for the suggestion on if(bp)!

Where is the code that sets BP to true? Also, having bp = true inside the Move() function makes no sense when Move() itself is only called when bp == true.
